# Word for count of undesirable events

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

TLDR: name for count of hiccups?

---

I'm trying to find a short¹ word for the count of *undesirable* events, up to some number of experiments, and tending to increase with the number of experiments as these undesirable things occur. The name should be usable for that count, and to name a function, in the math sense of that. A definition will be given, thus the word does not need to convey detail beyond undesirable. So far my best candidate is ***slack***. Usage could be

- The average ***slack** up to 1000* (experiments) for this device is 42
- The ratio of ***slack*** to experiment increases with temperature.
- The ***slack*** of a device is defined as the function that given *N*, returns it's  average ***slack** up to N* (experiments).
- This technique leaves more ***slack*** than this other one.
- It goes without saying that the ***slack*** is non-negative, and a non-decreasing function of the number of experiments in an experimental campaign.

The word should be recognizable by an educated international audience with English as a second language. It's OK, even desirable, if the word is colloquial, as long as it's universally safe for work.

What about ***slack*** versus ***leeway***, (updated: ***hiccup***, ***mishap***, though that's more for the event itself than for the count of it) ? Anything better?

Note: I rule our plain ***error*** or ***defect*** because they imply the device is defective, when ***slack*** is something resulting from a deliberate cost/benefit tradeoff.

---

¹ Update: I realize, late, that I need a diminutive, and that's why I want it to be short. What my ***slack*** counts really is integers that we want prime, but are not. The research field (number theory) I apply to actual devices (Smart Cards) treats integers with utmost respect. Thus calling them error, defect or failure would be offensive.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow "I rule our plain error or defect because they imply the device is defective, when slack is something resulting from a deliberate cost/benefit tradeoff." in context of the first example.  How is 42-slack-per-1000-experiments distinct from 42-defects-per-1000 or 42-failures-per-1000? (Or are you just stating that you just have a preference not to use those specific words?)

Comment: @LetEpsilonBeLessThanZero: what my slack counts is integers that we want prime, and but are not. Since the research field (number theory) treats integers with utmost respect, calling them error, defect or failure would offensive. I realize, late, that I want a diminutive, and unconsciously expressed this as short.

Comment: This use of "slack" doesn't seem familiar to me at all.

Comment: @Barmar: that's why I ask! Does "snag" sound any better where there is "slack"?

Comment: @fgrieu Since "slack" seems totally wrong, practically anything would sound better.

Comment: @fgrieu "Since the research field (number theory) treats integers with utmost respect, calling them error, defect or failure would be offensive." This sound like an emotional overreaction to me.  That being said, shouldn't "false-positive" be the most correct terminology for this kind of result?... You have some algorithm/calculation that you throw inputs through to find primes as the output with some of which being incorrect upon closer inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context you have provided, it appears that

a) the register needs to be formal but should be universally understood.

b) the word should be a generic that refers to undesirable events of any nature - not just failure or a lag in operation or lacking in something.

Considering these aspects, how about '***snag***'? The register is not very formal, though.

> snag noun [ C ] /snæɡ/  a problem or difficulty

(Cambridge English dictionary)

Comment: Had not thought of that one. I like it. Safe for work enough. I have used "familiar" incorrectly in my question, I meant something like colloquial (en Français "language famillier"). So snag is a perfect fit for that intent.

Comment: "Snag" is similar to "hiccup", "mishap", "error" and "defect" in that it refers to single events rather than the count of events.

Comment: The OP asked for a word meaning 'the count'. The answer offered means 'the thing being counted'. And yet the OP seems to have accepted. Funny.

Answer (score 4):

**Failure rate** or **failure-rate** is obviously regarded as a compound noun by [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/failure-rate); it gives the hyphenated compound (though the examples it gives all use the open compound). The examples also show the common broadening, for instance to relationships, it seems:

> **Failure-rate**:   The frequency with which an engineered system or component fails, expressed for example in failures per hour.
>
> - *Gabriel suspected there was nothing on the planet that might make her interested in an option that currently stood at failure rate of
>   ninety nine percent.*
> - *The reason for the high failure rate may be that couples who choose to cohabitate have more liberal attitudes about marriage and divorce.*
> - *Every method has a small failure rate and side effects.*
> - *In general the failure rate of the implants is only 1 percent after one year.*
> - *This treatment has a failure rate of about 1-2 percent, apparently due to the mother's sensitization during pregnancy rather than at
>   delivery.*

And from the [Sunday Times {via Collins}](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/failure-rate):

> - Agents said that one failed deal in ten was the mark of a good agent and that some would be experiencing a greater failure rate.

Comment: "Error rate" is another commonly-used closely-related term (at least it's commonly used in computing and statistics).

Answer (score 3):

## Deficit

> 1. deficiency in amount or quality. *a deficit in rainfall*
>
> 2a. lack or impairment in an ability or functional capacity.
> *cognitive deficits*,
> *a hearing deficit*
>
> 2b. DISADVANTAGE
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deficit)

The usage would change, slightly.

- The average *deficit* up to 1000 (experiments) for this device is 42 units (milliseconds, milliamps, millimeters).
- The *deficit* ratio increases with temperature.

Comment: Deficit has a tendency to suggest "less than zero", when the slack is non-negative.

Answer (score 2):

In the context you have provided, lag can be used. Lag is a particularly common in the gaming community.

Backlog is another words that can be used in contexts such as this. For e.g. backlog of unpaid bills.

Comment: Useful. Lag is great for shortness and undesirable, but is furiously associated with time, rather than a count. Backlog conveys count, bit is strongly associated with length of a queue growing and shrinking according to effort to reduce it, when slack can only increase with experiments. I'll add that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Among the other good suggestions, I might add:

**Slippage**

in its sense:  failure to maintain an expected level, fulfill a goal, meet a deadline, etc.

Individual instances could be *slips*; the verb could be *slipping* or even *slippaging*.

Comment: Slippage carries the notion of measure, which is good. But when we go from slips to slippage, we loose the notion of discrete events that can be counted. There's also the unexpected issue that to the French part of an audience that's not thinking in English, slips decidedly are underpants, so the English word happens to be not so SFW in Frenglish. It's true French equivalent "glissement" is also quite long. I was trying to exclude other English words from a close register when specifying SFW.